# How to prove $\int_0^1\sin(x+\frac{1}{x}) \, dx$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus

How to prove that?
I try to use the comparasion test, but i don't know with that function compare.

Comment: how do you know it is convergent? Alternating series test might be relevant, to apply to $\sin(\frac1x)$ near $0$.

Comment: @Mirko it's probably given

Comment: Why not just use the definition?

Comment: You are integrating a bounded function (bounded by 1) over a bounded interval (of length 1). Therefore, the absolute value of the integral must be less than or equal to $1\times1=1$

Comment: Your integral is absolutely convergent ( $\sin$ is bounded by 1). This implies that your integral converges.

Comment: @JulianMejia but is not important the point of discontinuity?

Comment: @Johnny discontinuity at one point doesn't matter. A point has measure $0$, the integral doesn't change no matter which value you put at zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$-1\le \sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\le1$$
And, therefore
$$-1\le \int_0^1\sin\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\le1$$

Comment: Boundedness of the integrand does not by itself imply convergence; it can still be non-integrable.

Answer (score 5):

As Azif said this function is bounded. It's continuous and consequently integrable on $[δ,1]$ and |$\int_o^{\delta} \sin(x+\frac{1}{x}) \mathrm{d}x| \le \delta$ which converges to $0$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0$ so it is intégrable.